# Which Build is generated when I archive my App in Xcode6?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, xcode6

I have an app which I want to distribute to the app store.

**When I do >Product > Archive does the app automatically build in `Release` or `Debug` config? Do I have to set this manually or is it always `Release`?**

Answer (score 1):

You can define `Release` or `Debug` in the scheme by tapping on Edit Scheme and selecting the `Build Configuration`. Take a look at below screenshot:

[image: Edit Scheme]

[image: Select Build Configuration]

**EDIT:** To get Production APNS token

1. Archive the build in release mode.
2. Ensure to sign it with an Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning profile.
3. Ensure profile is correct by following below:

> Verify that the entitlements in the provisioning-profile file are
>   correct. To do this, open the .mobileprovision file in a text editor.
>   The contents of the file are structured in XML. In the Entitlements
>   dictionary locate the aps-environment key. For a development
>   provisioning profile, the string value of this key should be
>   development; for a distribution provisioning profile, the string value
>   should be production.

Comment: I tried to do that but for my push token I get always the token I had received from the debug mode.

Comment: When building locally Xcode signs the app and always bind it to sandbox APNS. So you get test environment push token.

Comment: What do I have to do in order to get release token?

Comment: Can you please try with the steps I added in my post.

Comment: Question: Step 1: Is Archive automatically release mode or do I have to change something?

Comment: By default it should be in release mode. You can double check it with the steps I mentioned in the screenshots above.

Answer (score 0):

You can define **Release**  or **Debug** in the scheme by tapping on Edit Scheme and selecting the Build Configuration
Its better to cross check when you are uploading build to store.

Comment: You did not answer my question: When I do >Product > Archive does the app automatically build in Release or Debug config?

Comment: If you have not change this then default Archive will be in **Release** mode.